# Saving and formatting text file with Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, text, formatting

I have a **text file** composed by two rows and the following format:

```
"27 feb 2015","28 feb 2015","1 mar 2015",...
"1","2","3","4",...
```

How can I save these values in **two arrays** and plot them using **MATLAB**?

**EDIT**

The first line contains Strings between quotations and the second one integers between quotations.

Comment: Does your text file consist of quotations as well, or is it really just a CSV file which looks like: `27 feb 2015, 28 feb 2015, 1 mar 2015, ..., <newline> 1, 2, 3, 4, ...`?   If your text file doesn't contain formatting strings (i.e. `%s, %d`), please remove them from your question.  It's really confusing because I don't know whether or not the formatting string is part of the text file, or if you are putting them there to exemplify what format each entry is per line.

Comment: The first line contains string between quotations and the second integers between `"`

Comment: OK, so there are strings in between `""` separated by commas, and the second line has integers in between `""`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thx for editing

Comment: No problem.  Let me write an answer.  It's actually quite easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to read in the two lines as separate strings and parse out the data yourself using regular expressions.  Then from there, you can convert each date into a date number, plot the dates and if you want, you can plot the actual dates on the horizontal axis.

Best thing would be to use [`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) twice once you open up your file using [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html).  Assuming your file was stored in a file called `data.txt`, and making sure that you set the working directory to be where you stored the text file, do this first:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
first_row = fgetl(fid);
second_row = fgetl(fid);
fclose(fid);
```

`first_row` and `second_row` will contain character arrays that contain the first and second row of the text file.  We open up the file, read in the first two lines, then close the file with [`fclose`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fclose.html).  Next, we can very easily split up the dates using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).  Regular expressions try to find patterns in strings.  Specifically, we have a well defined pattern where you want to get out strings that are in between quotation characters.  Specifically, you want a bunch of characters that are digits, letters or spaces.  Use [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to help you do this.  You would extract out the dates by the following code:

```
dates = regexp(first_row, '\"([\w+ ]+)\",', 'tokens');
```

The first element is the string you want to parse, the second element is the pattern you're looking for.  Specifically, the pattern is `\"([\w+ ]+)\"`.  This rather bad looking statement means that you are looking for patterns where we start with a `"`, have a whole bunch of characters followed by spaces, then we end with another `"`.  I place `()` in between the quotations because I don't want the quotation characters in the output.  I use the `'tokens`' flag because this means that I want to get the actual characters within the `()`.  When I run the above line and display the output, we get:

```
>> celldisp(dates)

dates{1}{1} =

27 feb 2015


dates{2}{1} =

28 feb 2015


dates{3}{1} =

1 mar 2015
```

We do the same thing for the second row, but we look for digits only:

```
numbers = regexp(second_row, '\"(\d+)\",', 'tokens');
```

Here, the pattern we look for is `\"(\d+)\"`, which means that we want to look for a sequence of numbers in between quotations.  Showing this output gives:

```
>> celldisp(numbers);

numbers{1}{1} =

1


numbers{2}{1} =

2


numbers{3}{1} =

3


numbers{4}{1} =

4
```

Because `numbers` is a cell array, convert the elements to a numeric array with [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html):

```
numbers = cellfun(@(x) str2double(x{1}), numbers);
```

This goes through each element in the cell array, which is a **nested** cell, and we convert the number into an actual numerical value.  Remember, these are still characters.

Now, all you have to do is convert the dates to numbers, do our plotting, and if you want, you can convert the date numbers to actual dates.  So:

```
dates = cellfun(@(x) x{1}, dates, 'uni', 0);
datenums = datenum(dates, 'dd mmm yyyy');
```

`dates` is originally a nested cell array of strings, so we need to unpack out the strings so that we place each string into one cell array.  [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) converts a date string into a physical date number.  You provide a formatting string, and in your case, it's `dd mm yyyy`.

Now, all you have to do is plot the stuff:

```
plot(datenums, numbers);
set(gca, 'XTick', datenums);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', dates);
```

The first line plots our stuff.  The second and third lines rename the `x`-axis so that instead of numerical values, we have dates instead.

I made a sample text file that contains:

```
"27 feb 2015","28 feb 2015","1 mar 2015","2 mar 2015",
"1","2","3","4",
```

When I used the above sample, with the above code, we get:

[image]

---

For your copying and pasting pleasure, this is what the full code looks like:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
first_row = fgetl(fid);
second_row = fgetl(fid);
fclose(fid);

dates = regexp(first_row, '\"([\w+ ]+)\",', 'tokens');
dates = cellfun(@(x) x{1}, dates, 'uni', 0);

numbers = regexp(second_row, '\"(\d+)\",', 'tokens');
numbers = cellfun(@(x) str2double(x{1}), numbers);

datenums = datenum(dates, 'dd mmm yyyy');

plot(datenums, numbers);
set(gca, 'XTick', datenums);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', dates);
```

Comment: Best answer ever! You deserve a +2